# Lazard theorem, one direction

Tags: modules, free-modules, flatness

I'm trying to prove the Lazard theorem:Let M be an R-module. Then M is flat if and only if it is the colimit of a directed system of free finite R-modules.

I got this hint of one direction:

Proof. A colimit of a directed system of flat modules is flat, as taking directed colimits is exact and commutes with tensor product. Hence if M is the colimit of a directed system of free finite modules then M is flat.

I have some questions:
why do they say `flat` and not free in this sentence:
"directed system of flat"

Moreover I do not understand what is `exact` and how commuting with tensor product
helps to prove that the colimit is flat.

Comment: Is $R$ a commutative, unital ring?

Comment: @Arthur I think not commutative but unital.

Comment: What is your definition of flat? Many people use a definition involving `exact` and the tensor product

Comment: @JackSchmidt Tensoring mono with it gives mono.Does it make sense ?

Comment: This is very similar to the exact definition. A homomorphism is mono iff $0 \to A \to B$ is exact, that is, $\ker(A\to B) = im(0\to A)$. The image of 0 is 0, so this just says the kernel is 0. I think you can replace the word "exact" with "preserves mono" for purposes of the hint. Writing out all the details would be both an answer to your second question and a proof of one direction of lazard.

Comment: @JackSchmidt Can you please explain this sentence "Hence if M is the colimit of a directed system of free finite modules then M is flat." for a beginner ?